# Including additional libraries in OpenCV after compilation

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

When manually compiling the OpenCV library, one has to select what he/she wants to include by specifying in CMake all the things to include. If, for instance, I would like to include an additional library (for example CUDA support), can I just compile that separately or do I have to recompile the entire library? If former is the answer, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go with CUDA as an example. Library's some dll and lib files will have some dependices to CUDA and some won't. When you use Cmake to configure and generate make files it does create this files with your supplied configuration, CUDA on or off. So but later you want to change this configuration and recompile it again. This is what make is for. When you want to change something within the library and not want to compile it from beginnig.

So you should use Cmake again to generate new make files with your new configuration. You should use the same folders of first compilation to reduce required compile time. So when you change the configuration and generate new make files, it will have probably less compiling time than compiling the all library, because not every library has dependicies with new configuration.

But **there is an important issue here.** CUDA is a highly dependent library. When I checked source code there are defines which indicates if cuda is on or off. So in this case a change in CUDA configuration affects so much. If you ask me not just for CUDA for all other configuration changes, use a new fresh folder for new configuration and compilation. Because when you encounter a problem you would be at least sure that you have no compilation problems.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So from what I understood, it depends on which libraries I want to include. Some will have little dependencies and some higher. For those with higher dependencies, like in case of CUDA, it would be more easier to just recompile everything to avoid bugs and such. Correct?

Comment: Yeah exactly. But I would always recompile even for little dependicies just to be sure.